# How to manage hosts with multiple sites using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have this sample inventory file:

```
[web1] // Web Server 1 contains the following sites:
example1.com
example2.com

[web2] // Web Server 2 contains the following sites:
example3.com
example4.com
```

But whenever I run a playbook for example with `apt-get update` command it tries to iterate through all the sites in the given web servers above.

How do I run the playbook in the host itself and not the example*.com sites because it's redundant.

### EDIT

As requested here's the yaml file: (nothing fancy here.)

```
# Using all but --limit the execution to webservers
# I know I can use `webservers` but this was deliberate
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
    - // sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Show us a sample yaml file

Comment: @lain I don't think the yaml file is necessary, the playbook runs `all` the hosts listed. But I'm going to post it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporary solution is to create a different group for the web server itself and run the server specific configuration from there.

```
webserver1 ansible_host=10.10.1.2
webserver2 ansible_host=10.10.1.3

[webservers]
webserver1
webserver2

[web1]
example1.com
example2.com

[web2]
example3.com
example4.com
```

So I can run `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit webservers`.

Answer (score 0):

> hosts: all

This means that it will run on all listed hosts. If you want to restrict it to a particular group then you have to do that e.g.

```
[web1]
host1.example.com
host2.example.com

[web2]
host6.example.com
host10.example.com
```

with the above inventory

```
hosts: web1
```

would apply to host1, host2.

```
hosts: web2
```

would apply to host6, host10.

```
hosts: all
```

would apply to, well all of them

Comment: but notice i used `--limit webservers` so it will not apply to all. Anyway the real question is how can I restrict the plays to the web hosts and not the sites found on each host?

Answer (score 0):

inventory:

```
[webservers]
webserver1
webserver2
```

playbook:

```
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - { role: common, tag: common }
- hosts: webserver1
    - { role: host1.example.com, tag: host1.example.com }
    - { role: host2.example.com, tag: host2.example.com }
- hosts: webserver2
    - { role: host3.example.com, tag: host3.example.com }
    - { role: host3.example.com, tag: host4.example.com }
```

Roles:

```
host1.example.com/
  tasks/
    main.yml
  vars/
    main.yml
host2.example.com/
    ...
```

All sites on webserver1:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -l webserver1`

Site host3.example.com on it's webserver:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t host3.example.com`

Shell command on webservers group:

`ansible webservers -m shell -a "sudo apt-get update"`

You should check out [ansible best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html)